# jquery decode html entity &micro;

Tags: jquery, html, entity, decode

I figured out working with jquery and **html entities**, there is a problem with the html entity not **decoding** automatically, I guess.

I researched many and tried some jquery html entity decode options out there, but cannot for the life of me figure this out.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

using jquery library 3.1.1 btw.

This script that initially pulls apart and reorganizes into new elements works ok. It changes this:

```
   <ul class="productList">
    <li class="product">
    <p class="summary_description">
   [[25µg, ABP-NAB-BFGFAB]]
   </p>
   </li>
   </ul>
```

outputs into this:

```
<ul class="productList">
<li class="product">
<p class="summary_description">
<div class="prodosku">ABP-NAB-BFGFAB</div>
<div class="prodoweight">25&micro;g</div>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

> and displays it as 25& micro; (w/o space of course) but as you can see, the html entity &micro ; doesn't convert / decode to the µ symbol.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if( $(".categoryPage").length > 0 ) {
        $("#product-listing-container .productList li").each( function() {
    var content = $(this).val(".summary_description").html();
            content = content.substr( content.indexOf("[["), content.indexOf("]]"));

            var weight = '<div class="prodoweight">';
            var sku = '<div class="prodosku">';
            weight += content.substr( content.indexOf("[[") + 2, content.indexOf(",") - 2);
            weight += "</div>";
            sku += content.substr( content.indexOf(",") + 1, content.indexOf("]]") - content.indexOf(",") - 1);
            sku += "</div>";

    $(this).find(".summary_description").html(sku+weight);
        });
    } });
```

> Is there a way to make sure the &micro gets decoded to the µ symbol ???

I was thinking along the lines of something like this to make sure each li that contains the .prodoweight changes, but can't make it work.

```
  if( $(".productList li").length > 0 ) {
  var decoded = $(".prodoweight").html().text();
  $(".prodoweight").html(decoded);
  }
```

or trying with unicode???

```
   if( $(".productList li").length > 0 ) {
        var txt = $(".prodoweight").html();
        txt = txt.replace("\&micro\;", /\[\[([\w\s,\-\u00B5.&;])+\]\]/g);
        $(".prodoweight").html(txt);
    }
```

or maybe there is a better way to do this in the initial script ???  Thank you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed the line

```
var content = $(this).val(".summary_description").html();
```

to this:

```
var content = $(this).val(".summary_description").text();
```

and it worked like a charm.